# Using a list of files to create an array?

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, dictionary

So I have a group of tab-delineated files that have the following format:

[image]

and I want to create a tab-delineated file/table that shows the frequency of each value (in this case, fruits) based on whether they appear in which specific files:

[image]

My initial approach to this problem was to store each fruit in a defaultdict and append the file name and frequency count to the file like this:

```
import glob, os
from collections import defaultdict

file_list = glob.glob(input_directory + '*.txt')

master_list = defaultdict(list)
for file in file_list:
    shortname = os.path.basename(file)
    with open(file) as input:
        for line in file:
            info = line.rstrip().split('\t')
            fruit,frequency = info[0],info[1]
            master_list[fruit].append((shortname,frequency))
```

But after collecting all of this information, I don't have much of an idea as to how to check whether a specific fruit exists in a certain file and to output it.

I was initially thinking of using a numpy array as my data structure since you can modify the individual elements in the array (I believe).

Is there a way to check whether a specific fruit as an associated frequency value in each of the files and if so,what would be the best way to do so as well as export that information?

Answer (score 0):

Imho this looks like you want to use `pandas`. You can define one `DataFrame` and append the frequency for each file as a column.

```
import pandas as pd

master_list = pd.DataFrame(index=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas'])
for file in file_list:
    shortname = os.path.basename(file)
    master_list = master_list.join(
        pd.DataFrame(index=master_list.index,
                     data={file: np.zeros(master_list.index.size)}))
    with open(file) as input:
        for line in file:
            info = line.rstrip().split('\t')
            fruit, frequency = info[0], info[1]
            master_list[file][fruit] += frequency
```

If the frequency shall not be counted, you need to replace the last line `master_list[file][fruit] += frequency` with `master_list[file][fruit] = frequency`